# J7 Prime SamsungExperienceServices keeps stopping

Tags: samsung-mobile

Samsung J7 Prime always give an error saying **Samsung Experience Services keeps stopping**

Comment: Please give more information about your described problem. I think it lacks information. Find more information about this topice [here]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about Android usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this difficulty last couple of days and found the solution. Go to play store and type "Samsung Experience Service". Then select uninstall. store will ask to update. do update and restart your smart phone and then.... enjoy!!!